# How to set focus to an element through javascript parameter

Tags: javascript

Below is a function that I have been trying to call to set focus on a text box, but it is not doing so. I would be thankful if anyone can tell me how to do this.

Thanks in advance :)

address1 is the id of the text box.

```
function address_validation(address1)
{
        document.getElementById("address1").focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: 'address1' is a variable. Here your code is looking for an element with id 'address1' than taking address1's value as an id. Use address1 without quotes.

Comment: @ n_n `'address1'` is not variable but `address1` is.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `"address1"`  than `address1`. 
Your are supposing to get element by using dynamic id `address1` but you have used static one `"address1"`.

```
  function address_validation(address1){
      document.getElementById(address1).focus();
      return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#txt:focus{
    background:black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt"><BR>
<input type="button" onclick="btn()" value="set focus">
<script>
function btn(){
    var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
    txt.focus();
    return false;
};

</script>
</body>
```